# Center X of a programmatically created UIView to another UIView - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, constraints

Just to try it out I create a Button programmatically as below

```
UIBUtton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
[self.view insertSubview:button belowSubview:_testlabel];
```

I already have an existing label inside my view named _testlabel. I am using autolayout and I wanted to center my newly added button's X to the _testlabel, I tried the below code in every possible way I could:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
constraintWithItem:_testlabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button
attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

All I could do was center _testlabel's X to the newly added button, not the other way around. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to add button as a subView of _testLabel?

Comment: I am not adding it as a subview of _testlabel you see, I am adding it "below" _testlabel

Comment: That call will put it below in the view hierarchy, not geometrically. The documentation sucks!

Comment: I know, I used it to put it below in the view hierarchy anyway. That's not the issue, look at the second part. I am not trying to put it physically below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do this to both your button and your label:

```
    [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
    [_testlabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
```

and then add additional resizing constraints using AutoLayout constraint formatting lanaguage using:

```
[self.view addConstraints: ... constraintsWithVisualFormat ...];
```

and/or also using more

```
[self.view addConstraint: ... constraintWithItem ...]
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I have been busting my head for hours now... Thanks a lot!